# Get null value in parameter in actionresult from actionlink click on different controller actionmethod

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, actionlink, actionmethod

I am using Visual Studio 2015 with C# language and MVC version 4.

I am calling the actionmethod on different Controller on actionlink click event.

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.ListingDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), "MyActionMethod", "ControllerName", item.Id , null)
```

it calls the actionmethod correctly but I am getting null as a value in ActionMethod Id:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> MyActionMethod(string Id) // it is coming null here
{
      //Mycode
}
```

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have tried it before the same but getting the value null but now it's coming amazing magic don't know what happen but it's working thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of your parameter is `Id` so you need to create an object with that name

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    item.ListingDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"),
    "MyActionMethod",
    "ControllerName", 
    new { id = item.Id }, // change this
    null)
```

Comment: As per my knowledge I think I should not write id = item.Id right I can sent direct variable na! May be I could wrong.

Comment: You current code will not add a route value so its creating just `../ControllerName./MyActionMethod`, not `../ControllerName./MyActionMethod/someValue`

Comment: Note I rejected you edit - The `DefaultModelBinder` is not case sensitive - `new { id = item.Id }` or `new { Id = item.Id }` or `new { iD = item.Id }` or `new { ID = item.Id }` are all identical and will correctly bind.

Comment: ohhh ok I see, I thought that by sending id by default it will take as a ../ControllerName./MyActionMethod/someValue but it's wrong anyway I got your point sir and also the edit rejection point as well.

Comment: To explain the first point - the 4th parameter is `object` and the method generates a route value or query string value for each property of the object. In your case your object is `int` and `int` has no properties so nothing is generated. If you were to change it to `string id` and set the 4th parameter as (say) "padhiyar" it would generate `...?length=8` because `string` has a property named `length` and there are 8 characters in "padhiyar"

Comment: it's amazing explanation sir now I understand only string and those types who has properties will generate the 4th parameter not int ohhhh ok I see.